# Hello Dagger2 crashes on Android Studio

Tags: android, dagger-2

I am playing with Dagger2 in order to understand how it works. I have just created a "hello dagger2" basic project but it crashes

I have three classes: Bread, Flour and Water. Bread has a dependency from Flour and Water.

class Bread:

```
    public class Bread {

    private Water water;
    private Flour flour;

    @Inject
    public Bread (Water water, Flour flour){
        this.water = water;
        this.flour = flour;
    }
}
```

class Water:

```
public class Water {

    int waterQuantity;

    public Water(int waterQuantity){
    this.waterQuantity = waterQuantity;
    }
}
```

class Flour:

```
    public class Flour {

    private int flourQuantity;

    public Flour(int flourQuantity){
        this.flourQuantity = flourQuantity;
    }
}
```

As well I have implemented the module and the component

Module:

```
@Module
public class BreadModule {

    @Provides @Singleton
    Bread provideBread(Water water, Flour flour){
     return new Bread(water, flour);
    }
}
```

Compoment:

```
@Singleton
@Component (modules = {BreadModule.class})
public interface BreadComponent {

    Bread getBread();
}
```

The error I am facing is :

> Error:(13, 11) error: com.example.llisas.testingdagger2.model.Water
>   cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an
>   @Provides-annotated method.
>   com.example.llisas.testingdagger2.module.BreadModule.provideBread(com.example.llisas.testingdagger2.model.Water
>   water, com.example.llisas.testingdagger2.model.Flour flour)
>   [parameter: com.example.llisas.testingdagger2.model.Water water]

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While trying to provide `Bread`, Dagger2 needs objects of type `Water` and `Flour`. You need to add @Provide methods in your module that provide `Water` and `Flour`.

For example:

```
@Provides
Water provideWater() {
     return new Water(1); // instead of 1, you can add any other default value
}
```

If you have an integer in this method, you have to provide that as well, as shown below:

```
@Provides @Named("defaultWaterQuantity")
int provideWaterQuantity() {
    return 1;
}

@Provides
Water provideWater(@Named("defaultWaterQuantity") int waterQuantity){
     return new Water(waterQuantity);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, both method created , receiving an integer(quantity as parameter) and other error is got .  Provides Singleton
    Water provideWater(int quantity){
        return new Water(quantity);
    }

Comment: Error:(13, 11) error: java.lang.Integer cannot be provided without an Inject constructor or from an Provides-annotated method.
com.example.llisas.testingdagger2.module.BreadModule.provideBread(com.example.llisas.testingdagger2.model.Water water, com.example.llisas.testingdagger2.model.Flour flour)
[parameter: com.example.llisas.testingdagger2.model.Water water]
com.example.llisas.testingdagger2.module.BreadModule.provideWater(int quantity)
[parameter: int quantity]

Comment: As long as your methods have parameters (in this case, integers) you will need to keep providing them until the provide method does not have parameters. With integers, you have to add the @Name("description") annotation to distinguish between different types of integers you are providing

Comment: I am so sorry I dont get what you mean . Could you please add a piece of code as example

Comment: @JeCuRo please check the edit and see if you have any questions